# how to improve the resolution of the PSD using Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have and audio signal, which I read with Matlab, and use pwelch to get its PSD, here ist the code that I'm using

```
[x,Fs] = audioread('audioFile.wav');
x= x(:,1) %  mono
[xPSD,f] = pwelch(x,hamming(512),16,1024,Fs);
plot(f,xPSD);
```

since the `FS=96000` and I'm only interrested in Frequencies bellow 5khz,  I would like to calculate the PSD only for the area, and also being able to adjust the resolution of the PSD ! any idea hwo to do that !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calculating PSDs with `pwelch`, there is always a trade-off between spectral resolution, number of averages and the amount of data you need. My preferred way to use it is:

```
[psd_x, freq] = pwelch(x, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft, fsample);
```

A few differences with your code:

1. I prefer to use [hann](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hann.html) windows, since I have bad experiences with hamming windows, they are not very good if your signal contains for example a large DC component. See [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Comparison_of_windows), which shows that the roll-off of `hann` is much better, at the only cost of a slightly higher first sidelobe.
2. I use windows that overlap 50% (by using `noverlap = nfft/2`), in this way you 'get the most out of your data'. In your case, there is only 16/512 = 3% overlap between windows, and since the window function is close to zero at its edges, the data points at the edges do not contribute as much as points in the middle of a window. With half-overlapping windows this effect is much smaller. Making the overlap bigger than 50% is useless, you will get more averages, but since you will use the same points many times, this does not add any extra information. Just stick to 50%.
3. I usually make the length of the fft (fourth argument to pwelch) the same as the window length. The only case you want to have this different is when you use [zero-padding](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/741), which has limited use.

There are a few simple formulas, which you should memorize when working with `pwelch` and similar functions:

- The spectral resolution is given by the window length only: `df = 1 / t_window`
- The length of a single window is `t_window = nfft / f_sample`.
- With half-overlapping windows, the total amount of needed data is `t_total = t_window * (n_average + 1) / 2`
- For one-sided spectra, the number of spectral bins of the PSD is `nfft / 2`.
- [Nyquist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate): `f_max = f_sample / 2`

To get a reasonably smooth spectrum, I would typically use on the order of 20 averages. Combining the equations above and filling in the required spectral resolution then gives you the total length of data you need. Or the other way around, if you only have a limited amount of data available, you could calculate the frequency resolution you can obtain.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what it is the problem with zero Padding  ?

Comment: See the linked question, it will only give you 'fake' resolution. It will give you more points, but these form more or less a smooth interpolation between the points you would get without zero-padding. You do not magically get extra spectral resolution. Think of it as conservation of information, if you use 1000 points of data, adding 9000 zeros will not give you a spectrum with 10000 independent bins. The only use-case I know for zero-padding is if you want to accurately determine the frequency of a single sharp line in the spectrum.

Comment: even after running the zero paddibnng I still get the same length of the PSD

Comment: Are you sure? To zero-pad by a factor 4, you would probably have to do `pwelch(x, hann(nfft), nfft/2, nfft*4, fsample)`. But as I said, this is probably useless.

Comment: Zero-padding is not useless, even though it only interpolates, as it produces a very high quality and smooth interpolation for high-density or zoomed-in plotting.