# MATLAB, averaging multiple fft's ,coherent integration

Tags: matlab, fft

I have audio record. 
I want to detect sinusoidal pattern. 
If i do regular fft i have result with bad SNR. 
for example
my signal contents 4 high frequencies:
[image]

fft result:
[image]

To reduce noise i want to do Coherent integration as described in this article: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.729.1.109/1/

but i cant find any MATLAB examples how to do it. Sorry for bad english. Please help )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look at spectra almost every day, but I never heard of 'coherent integration' as a method to calculate one. As also mentioned by Jason, coherent integration would only work when your signal has a fixed phase during every FFT you average over.

It is more likely that you want to do what the article calls 'incoherent integration'. This is more commonly known as calculating a [periodogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram) (or [Welch's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch_method), a slightly better variant), in which you average the squared absolute value of the individual FFTs to obtain a power-spectral-density. To calculate a PSD in the correct way, you need to pay attention to some details, like applying a suitable [Fourier window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) before doing each FFT, doing the proper normalization (so that the result is properly calibrated in i.e. Volt^2/Hz) and using half-overlapping windows to make use of all your data. All of this is implemented in Matlab's [pwelch](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) function, which is part of the signal-processing toolbox. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662651/2647279) to a similar question about how to use pwelch.

Answer (score 1):

Integration or averaging of FFT frames just amounts to adding the frames up element-wise and dividing by the number of frames.  Since MATLAB provides vector operations, you can just add the frames with the `+` operator.

```
coh_avg = (frame1 + frame2 + ...) / Nframes
```

Where `frameX` are the complex FFT output frames.

If you want to do non-coherent averaging, you just need to take the magnitude of the complex elements before adding the frames together.

```
noncoh_avg = (abs(frame1) + abs(frame2) + ...) / Nframes
```

Also note that in order for coherent averaging to work the best, the starting phase of the signal of interest needs to be the same for each FFT frame.  Otherwise, the FFT bin with the signal may add in such a way that the amplitudes cancel out.  This is usually a tough requirement to ensure without some knowledge of the signal or some external triggering so it is more common to use non-coherent averaging.

Non-coherent integration will not reduce the noise power, but it will increase signal to noise ratio (how the signal power compares to the noise power), which is probably what you really want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the "spectrogram" function in Matlab, which computes the short time Fourier transform(STFT) of an input signal.

[STFT](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=short%20time%20fourier%20transform&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FShort-time_Fourier_transform&ei=ypC6U7yDJ-Wf0QWXuoH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNFevkin1Q-qwRoVrtEdoCCPb1AcfQ&sig2=QTwRQo1orVT3g_w8OYjcvA&bvm=bv.70138588,d.d2k)

[Spectrogram](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=spectrogram%20matlab&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Fsignal%2Fref%2Fspectrogram.html&ei=c5G6U-fmOueQ0QW9voCACA&usg=AFQjCNHHgOq0PkMupcSU6EKSCPWoPwm3WQ&sig2=rlpqSJGYOqsEsp7UGoUfNw&bvm=bv.70138588,d.d2k)